# How to maintain the "updated_at" variable in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am  making an application in which there is only model that is Project and in the view of the project i can see the table with the variables that generate automatically i.e created
_at and updated_at.
I want to keep track the updated_at variable means that if user updates the project 10 times it will show the updated_at variable 10 times so that i can track the project model.

Comment: Where do you want to show it? Do you mean you don't just want to be able to see when it was last updated, but also updates before that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need another model to keep track of the changes over time and to use the active record callbacks whenever your Project model is created.

Let's say you are tracking your changes through a model called ProjectChanges

```
rails g model ProjectChange project_id:integer change:string when:datetime
```

then add implement the callback hooks into your Project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_changes
  after_create :record_update( 'create' )
  after_save :record_update( 'update' )
  ...
  def record_update( what_happened )
    # not forgetting to add attr_accessible to the ProjectChange class if you want to mass assign like this
    ProjectChange.new( { :change => what_happened, :when => Time.now } )
  end
end
```

Comment: see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html for details on active record callbacks

Comment: Sorry it requires 15 reputations to vote up an answer which i don't have .:(